# Use absolute paths in sbt stage

Tags: amazon-ec2, playframework, playframework-2.3

On Amazon EC2, I try to run my application in background. So I do sbt stage, and then nohup target/universal/stage/bin/my-app-name & .
During application lifetime, I generate some files in conf/ folder, and that works perfect with sbt run.

So, for example, I pass relative path conf/generated/res, and for sbt it uses /home/user/path/to/app/conf/generated/res, but for my-app-name script (generated by sbt stage) it uses smth like /home/user/path/to/app/target/universal/stage/bin/app/conf/generated/res, and gets NoSuchFileException. Same when I pass absolute path, it gets appended to generated by sbt stage folder.
So, how can I fix this problem?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Try to give some more detail please. You are passing the path as a command parameter, as a application.conf property or something else? Can you put the commands you are using?

Comment: I `used target/universal/stage/bin/my-app-name to start`. In my code I accessed files as `new File(path)`, and `play.Play.application.getFile(path)` did the trick. (got tip from mailing list, thanks alex s)